# RichTextBox line Length =1

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, richtextbox

> RichTextBox1.text =

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

i wounder if i can delete all lines to be 1 line length

like this

> RichTextBox1.text =

```
12345
```

im using Button1

i tried

```
  RichTextBox1.Lines.Length = 1
```

But its not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RichTextBox1.Lines.Length` is a number of lines in the text. `Lines` is the array of all the lines, `Length` is its element count.

Between each of these is an `Enviroment.NewLine` character, which makes them go to a new line.

The way to do this is to remove that character manually. The simplest way is to just add the lines together as a string, and make that the new value. Put this in button 1:

```
Dim newLine As String = ""
For i = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
    newLine = newLine & RichTextBox1.Lines(i)
Next
RichTextBox1.Text = newLine
```

Comment: Big thanks its work, But a small edit from you,here

 RichTextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "")

        Dim newLine As String = ""
        For i = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
            newLine = newLine & RichTextBox1.Lines(i)
        Next
        RichTextBox1.Text = newLine

Comment: @Beginner01 You can also do this in one line: `RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(String.Empty, RichTextBox1.Lines)`

Answer (score 0):

I've used StringBuilder to create some sample text, then I remove of new newline characters from the example with a simple replace.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("1");
sb.AppendLine("2");
sb.AppendLine("3");
sb.AppendLine("4");
sb.AppendLine("5");

// This is what your after
sb.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine,string.Empty);
```

Be sure to let us know how you go and welcome :D

Comment: Ohh, I didn't used C#, But i can guess it also work, Big ty For your help, it already sloved, Big Ty.

Comment: Ah my bad didn't see the Vb.net Tag. It's practically identical from memory.

Comment: No, it was my bad, cause i taged general viual basic. Big ty Again for your help.

Comment: Use `sb.Append` instead of `sb.AppendLine` to avoid having to use that Replace function.

Comment: @LarsTech, Hey mate While you are correct I only used AppendLine replicate the example at hand.